# Python raw input with loop of counting

Tags: python

I'd like to output the `raw_input` looping including the numbers which have been given.

```
amount = int(raw_input("Enter number? "))
for item in range(amount):
    input = raw_input("#"), amount
```

**Actual output:**

```
Enter number? 2
# 
#
```

**Goal:**

```
Enter number? 2
#1
#2
```

Is this possible?

---

EDIT:
Wauw, i'm getting a lot of responses very quickly. Thank you all for your effort.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: `for item in range(1, amount + 1): print('#{}'.format(item))`

Comment: @vishes_shell `range(amount, 1)` produces an empty sequence.

`In [23]: list(range(2, 1))`
`Out[23]: []`

Comment: @E.Ducateme i muddle up with enumerate, my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should produce the result you show as your goal...

```
amount = int(raw_input('Enter number? '))
for item in range(1, amount + 1):
    print('#' + str(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
amount = input("Enter number? ")
for item in range(int(amount)):
  print ("#%i" % ( item))
```

Example for python 3

Comment: Works with some editing, but it starts with 0 instead of 1.
(It works tho!)

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
amount = int(raw_input("Enter number? "))
for item in range(amount):
  out = '#'+str(item)
  input = raw_input(out), amount
```